# Web Expression 4, html 5, The property is marked invalid because it's not supported by the current schema, "border-radius" not working

Tags: html, css, expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

I am quite new to Expression Web. I use Microsoft Expression Web 4. I don't know why but I can't use border-radius on button.
The property is marked invalid because it's not supported by the current schema.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <h1 style="width: 868px">Flashcards</h1>
                <div>
                    
                    <button class="button1">
                    Add Flashcard
                    </button>
                    <button class="button1">
                    Delete Flashcard
                    </button>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="createmabox">
            <label for="question">Questions</label>
            <textarea id="question"></textarea>
            <br>
            <label for="answer">Answers</label>
            <textarea id="answer"></textarea>
            <div>
                <button onclick="AddFC()" class="button1">Save</button>
                <button onclick="CancelFCBox()" class="button1">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap');

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}

body{
    font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    background-color:#F5F5F5
}

header{
    background-color:#3E8BFF
}

button{
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:4px;
    
}
```

The Error shown is:
The property is marked invalid because it's not supported by the current schema

Answer (score -1):

That might be due to schema setup by default by expression web 4 which is 2.1

Page Editor Options >> Authoring >>

you should see the 'Document declaration type' and 'CSS schema' options with drop-down menus

watch this video for more clarity:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bK_5GJz_bM&ab_channel=PaulBolton